# Dojo: How do I connect an onchange handler to a select box in a dialog loaded with xhr?

Tags: ajax, dialog, dojo

This may be obvious but I can't figure out how to get it done.

I have a Dojo Dialog that I populate with data using href.

```
var newDialog = new Dialog({
  title: 'Here is my dialog',
  style: 'width: 50%',
  href: 'path/to/content/script'
});
```

The dialog is shown when the user clicks a button:

```
var showDialog_button = new Button({
  label: "Create new scrum",
  onClick: function(){
    newDialog.show();
    dojo.connect(dojo.byId('select1'), 'onChange', select1_onchange);
  }
}, 'button_id');
```

The dialog contains a couple of select boxes that need to be connected: When an option is selected in one of them, the other needs to change as well (one contains a list of groups, and the other contains a list of members of that group - so when group X is selected, the other select should only show members of X).

But the problem is that because I load the dialog asynchronously I end up trying to connect an onchange handler before the dialog is done loading.

How do I wait until after the dialog has been loaded? I have tried calling `newDialog.startup` in order to load the dialog at once but that doesn't seem to help me either.

Help anyone?

Answer (score 1):

The dialog.show() method returns a dojo.Deferred that resolves when the display animation is complete.

You can therefore use dojo.when or dojo.then to do whatever needs to be done after the dialog finishes rendering.

In your example, something like this should work :

```
var connectEvent = null; 

var showDialog_button = new Button({
    label: "Create new scrum",
    onClick: function(){
        newDialog.show().then(function(){
            connectEvent = dojo.connect(dojo.byId('select1'), 'onChange', select1_onchange);
        }
    }
}, 'button_id');

// and later on, when the event is no longer needed...
connectEvent && dojo.disconnect(connectEvent);
```

Alternatively, you could use dojo 1.7.2's [dijit/on](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/on) to make it better, using a syntax like this :

```
showDialog_button.on("click", function(response) {
    var onShowEvt = dialog.on("show", function(e) { 
        onShowEvt.remove();
        // Connect your other events here
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmm I can't seem to make that work. Nothing at all happens when I call `newDialog.on()` or `on(newDialog, ...)`.

Comment: +1 looks like a clean solution to me. I only went w/ the connect approach cause I figured Thomas might not be familiar with Deferred and didn't want to discuss the 1.7 v. <1.6 issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the dialog to open before connecting to it:

```
var showDialog_button = new Button({
    label: "Create new scrum",
    onClick: function(){
        newDialog.show();
        var showHandle = dojo.connect(newDialog, 'onShow', function () {
            dojo.disconnect(showHandle);
            dojo.connect(dojo.byId('select1'), 'onChange', select1_onchange);
        });
    }
}, 'button_id');
```

Comment: *Edited* sorry I'm getting sleepy.

Comment: Finally! I have been fighting this problem for days now and have been reading through lots and lots of documentation and examples - but none of them did what I needed.

I ended up with a working solution where I used a Deferred to wait for a nested Ajax call to fetch the dialog content - using the Deferred success branch I was able to connect an event handler to my select box. But I just seemed unlikely that I needed to write that much code for such a simple task.

So thank you - you saved me from going crazy! :)